# What are some specific reasons why one would use SphinxAPI over SphinxQL?

Tags: c++, api, search, search-engine, sphinx

Are there any capabilities that one inherently lacks that the other doesn't?

SphinxQL (according to benchmarks on the Sphinx blog) returns queries faster than SphinxAPI for interpreted languages and the premise of such a comparison would likely be that the functionalities present in both are the same.

Why the API then?

Any clarity on this issue is much appreciated.

(This is about the C++ based open source search engine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a satisfactory answer:

SphinxQL is simply ***a language*** for querying Sphinx.

SphinxAPI is a ***framework that allows you to compute results*** based on the queries.

The queries could still be via SphinxQL or they could be via the API's syntax...it doesn't matter...SphinxQL and the SphinxAPI are different objects that accomplish different things (as highlighted above)

Answer (score 1):

SphinxAPI is a legacy. That is why I'd rather go with a flow with a API than switch to SphinxQL in production. But for new projects SphinxQL is the only choice as it is evolve quicker and gets all features first. The next big thing that using SphinxQL you don't tie to developer of API for not officially supported languages or platform instead you could use any MySQL client \ library.